# Pinhole camera projection matrix explained

Tags: math, graphics, camera, projection

[image]I'm trying to solve the attached question after reading some material about pinhole cameras and how their projection matrix are set and I'm still not sure I understand all the math.
in the attached question, when moving the COP of the camera to -2Zp as I understand I basically increase the focal view for the camera which basically gives me the same matrix as the one given only now the 3rd element of row 3 is 1/3Zp and not 1/Zp, is that correct?

if so, how would you calculate the new position of t, multiplying it by the new matrix I got give me (0, Yp, 2/3)T. is the solution to make sure that the last number is 1 and not 2/3 so I get (0,2Yp/3, 1). can someone explain how homogeneous coordinates work in this case?

Besides that c is pretty clear, I will get an orthographic projection.
Can someone help with section d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to draw a diagram. You can make things simpler by ignoring the x coordinate which puts everything in 2D. In this simpler diagram to find the projection of a point t, onto the plane PP simply draw a line from the position of the pinhole to the point. This makes it very easy to work out from the diagram where each point should be projected to. You can use this to check your calculations from the matrices.

You have half the answer, if we had a pinhole at the origin and the plane was a distance 3Zp away the matrix would be

```
    ( 1   0   0     0   )
M = ( 0   1   0     0   )
    ( 0   0   1/3Zp 0   )
```

This only works if the pinhole is at the origin. In part a) its not.

What you need to do is apply a translation. In case a) translate everything so COP2 is at the origin, apply the projection, then apply the inverse of the translation. Thing work easier if we add a forth row to M

```
    ( 1   0    0      0 )
M = ( 0   1    0      0 )
    ( 0   0    1      0 )
    ( 0   0    1/3Zp  0 ) Note modified form.
```

A translation of distance d along the z axis is given by

```
    ( 1   0   0   0 )
T = ( 0   1   0   0 )
    ( 0   0   1   d )
    ( 0   0   0   1 )
```

The inverse will simply be

```
    ( 1   0   0   0 )
T'= ( 0   1   0   0 )
    ( 0   0   1  -d )
    ( 0   0   0   1 )
```

To get your final projection matrix find

```
T' M T.
```

Finally we go from 4D (x,y,z,w) to 3D (x,y,w) by dropping the third coordinate. You can do this by multiplying by a 3X4 matrix.

Note see [Transformation matrix section perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) for the correct form of the perspective projection.

To make thing explicit let a=Zp. The translation is

```
    ( 1   0   0   0    )
T = ( 0   1   0   0    )
    ( 0   0   1   -2 a )
    ( 0   0   0   1    )
```

and the projection onto a plane 3Zp from origin is

```
    ( 1   0    0        0 )
M = ( 0   1    0        0 )
    ( 0   0    1        0 )
    ( 0   0    -1/(3a)  0 )
```

Find T' M T which turns out to be

```
    ( 1   0    0       0    )
N = ( 0   1    0       0    )
    ( 0   0   1/3    -2/3 a )
    ( 0   0  -1/(3a)  2/3   )
```

We apply to our two points

```
    (  0  )   (  0  )    (  0  )
 N  (  Yp ) = (  Yp ) -> (  Yp )
    ( -a  )   ( -a  )    ( -a  )
    ( 1   )   (  1  )

    (  0  )   (  0     )    (  0      )
 N  (  Yp ) = (  Yp    ) -> (  3/4 Yp )
    ( -2a )   ( -4/3 a )    ( -a      )
    ( 1   )   (  4/3   )
```

Where the last step is dividing by w so we have (x,y,z) coordinates lying on the plane z=-a=-Zp. These agree with what we get from the diagram. If you want you could drop the 3rd row of N.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that maybe I have to use translation but I wasn't sure. so b would just be applying the matrix on p checking that it remains the same, then applying on t, c is just orthographic projection, then what about d? I assume that if my COP is changing and I wanna keep t at the same projection I have to keep the same ratio or something. how do I do it?

Comment: By the way, regarding a, whats the difference between having the PP at 3Zp or having the COP at -2Zp and the PP at Zp? and another thing, if you are right with using translation, doesn't it mean that M stays the same so it should have 1/Zp instead of 1/3Zp?

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to add the 4th row, as I understand you are supposed to go from 3d to 2d, because the Z is constant at Zp, so going from 4 homogeneous coordinates you use the 4X3 matrix and get 3 numbers where the last is not Z, its W and you have to divide by it so it would be 1. This is why if you take point t and multiply it by the matrix in the question you would get (0,Yp,2)T and if you want to display it in homogeneous coordinates you divide by 2 and get (0,0.5Yp,1)T as written in the question. right?

Comment: I think you need 4X4 matrices for the intermediate steps. I think the projection matrix as stated in the question is wrong. It should be as given in my amended answer.

Comment: (Strike previous comment) 

Ah yes I see whats going on. I misunderstood quite what the projection matrix was about. I think you will find things easier to use 4X4 matrices for the intermediate steps and only go down to 3D at the very last step.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, I tried multiplying the matrices as you said using a matrix calculator, but then when I multiply the result matrix with P I get a different point I get (0,Yp,-Zp,2) which looks incorrect. Can you please show me the calculations for getting M and then check that P remains in the same position? because right now I'm not really convinced that its true. Also if I try to make a diagram like you said and use similar triangles its not very clear to me why you need to translate everything because if you do then you also move PP. moving COP and leaving PP looks like changing f

Comment: I'm looking at this PPT as explanation on the projection matrix: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse576/08sp/lectures/projection.ppt

Comment: The purpose of doing the translation is really a change in coordinates. First we change coordinates so COP2 is the origin, do the projection, then change coordinates back again.

Comment: its not explaining why it needs to be done, its like saying, the purpose of doing translation is for doing a translation? as I see it if you want to move COP2 to the origin and apply translation you are also changing the position of PP. if I draw a simple pinhole camera diagram, in 2d since I can ignore X then its basically the same thing as taking a camera with f= 3Zp. if I'm wrong please correct me and show me how to construct the final matrix. a test would be according to section b to multiply by point p and see that it remains in the same place

Comment: See the updated answer. I've made it explicit. You get extra non zero terms in the final matrix.

Comment: thanks, I'm checking out the calculations right now, but shouldn't the first translation be 2a and the reverse -2a. are you translating COP2 to origin or vice versa. Edit: or a=-zp, I don't understand why in M its -1/3a, shouldn't it be positive?

Answer (score 0):

ok so now regarding C and D.
in C I assume that if you move COP along the Z axis to infinity you get an orthographic projection. but I'm not sure if the matrix would be:

```
    ( 1   0    0    0 )
M = ( 0   1    0    0 )
    ( 0   0    0    0 )
```

or

```
    ( 1   0    0    0 )
M = ( 0   1    0    0 )
    ( 0   0    0    Zp )
```

With D I have not idea, you need to somehow keep the ratio so that t will be projected the same way, and I understand that you have to pick the Z coordinate for PP as a function of the new COP, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You can do the same calculation but have a=distance from the origin to the plane and b=distance from COP to the origin. You can calculate the resulting projection matrix. Then take limits as b->infinity. The final solution is like your second matrix but the bottom right term is just 1. It need to be this otherwise you would get some scaling when you convert out of homogeneous coords.

Comment: For part d) use the general matrix from the previous comment. Then apply this matrix to t. You will then need to solve for a.